# How can I show only the first result in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ecommerce angularjs project that uses `ng-repeat`. On a product detail page, I am getting more than 1 result. So I have to use `ng-repeat`.

How can I show only the first result/array of the response?

My response looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is just show that first response [0]. I don't want to show the 2nd array until later.

Controller:

```
unarcoQS.controller ('prodCtrl', ['$scope', 'productService', 'ngCart', 
'$route', '$routeParams', '$resource', function($scope, productService, ngCart,
$route, $routeParams, $resource) 
{
id = $routeParams.PartNumber;

productService.query({PartNumber: id}, function(response){
   $scope.products = response;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-7" ng-repeat="product in products">
    <div class="product-title">{{product[0].Description}}</div>
    <div class="product-desc">{{product[0].Category}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the `$index` to track the index and only show the o indexed value

```
  <ul ng-repeat="product in products" ng-show="$index == 0">
      <div class="product-title">{{product.Description}}</div>
      <div class="product-desc">{{product.Category}}</div>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. Especially since I need to do it in other places on the page too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`product in products[0]`

`product in products ng-show="$index ==0"`

`product in product | limitTo:1` 
Choose one and use

Answer (score 0):

"What I want to do is just show that first response [0]. I don't want to show the 2nd array until later."

Thanh answer is pretty good, but could you elaborate on "until later": if you want to keep the array but display only the first item on this page you can do the following:

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="product-title">{{products[0].Description}}</div>
    <div class="product-desc">{{products[0].Category}}</div>
</div>
```

Unless you have a need to use the second item in the ng-repeat I would avoid it.